# Remove slash if URL starts with #

Tags: jquery, permalinks

I am using smoothscroll on a wordpress website which works in some browsers but not others, simply because Wordpress keeps putting a trailing slash in the middle of the URL.

If I click an internal link (eg. #gallery) to scroll to siteurl.com#gallery it actually goes to siteurl.com/#gallery and this does not work in some browsers.

However I do not want to add a function that removes the trailing slash altogether as then other pages will not be linked to (eg. siteurl.com/news).

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: I believe siteurl.com/#gallery is the correct behaviour. Everything after the # is part of the path fragment. That being said, it's part of the path. The path begins after a / :P

Comment: Where is the `/` that you want to remove, in the page's address bar (`document.location`) or in the URLs of the `<a>` elements (in the `href` property)? If it's in the address bar, then removing it would likely trigger a page-reload (causing the `/` to reappear on the subsequently-reloaded page) as it's only the component *after* the `#` that can be changed by the browser without triggering a reload.

Comment: On pages `onload` event(you can use javascript or jQuery) check the url by searching for the char `#` in the current url checking if the previous char is `/`. If so delete that char and go to that url.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, I have since found that it should work whether the / is there or not, it just seemed to be Safari that it wasn't working with but got it working by putting the full path in the href="" (siteurl.com#gallery) and safari seemed to work with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changed the code to the following which works in all browsers regardless of any trailing slash:

```
// Add smooth scrolling to all links
jQuery("a").on('click', function(event) {

// Make sure this.hash has a value before overriding default behavior
if (this.hash !== "") {
  // Prevent default anchor click behavior
  event.preventDefault();

  // Store hash
  var hash = this.hash;

  // Using jQuery's animate() method to add smooth page scroll
  // The optional number (800) specifies the number of milliseconds it takes to scroll to the specified area
  jQuery('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: jQuery(hash).offset().top
  }, 800, function(){

    // Add hash (#) to URL when done scrolling (default click behavior)
    window.location.hash = hash;
  });
} // End if
});
```